# How to add a WindowListener to an external event

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jframe, visible

This is my code I have developed. This is the main program which holds and executes each external JFrame for my Game. chooseGender is an external program which is nothing but a JFrame and its components.

My goal for this is when chooseGender executes, it has 2 buttons for options (male, female) when the user picks one, an actionListener would set the frame to setVisible(false) and then have a WindowClosing event open the next JFrame, (chooseRace). This would happen for several more frames but these 2 are for learning purposes. I appreciate the help in advance. :)

So my question is, how would I go about adding a WindowListener to chooseGender in this program so I can close it and open the next one?

```
package javagame;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main implements WindowListener {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

             EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new chooseGender().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

          EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new chooseRace().setVisible(false);
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to implement this may be just using modal [`JDialogs`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html).

The code would be similar to the following:

```
main {

    new chooseGender().setVisible(true);
    new chooseRace().setVisible(true);
    new chooseAge...

}
```

You would want to implement a `WidowListener` similar to the following:

```
public class OpenNewWindowWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        // in here open the next window.
    }
}
```

And add that window listener to the correct frame:

```
// In the constructor for the JFrame
addWindowListener(new OpenNewWindowListener());
```

And, each of those classes would `extend` `JDialog` and, in their constructors use [`setModal(true)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal(boolean)).

Comment: Hold on, I'll have to research that. I haven't gotten that far into Java yet.

Comment: Er, They would still be JFrames though correct, and would still execute the way* I would like?

Comment: @Nick, you would need to make them `JDialogs`.  `JDialogs` are very similar to JFrames.

Comment: Thats not what I am wanting to do though. I'm trying to use them as JFrames. Thank you for the suggestion, it has made me look into JDialogs and I will implement them in the future, but I really really need to learn JFrames. This is one of the challenges I am facing right now and would like to learn how to do this correctly.

Comment: Which leads me back to my original question of, where would I add my windowListener in this program to sense if chooseGender has closed?

Comment: @Nick, ok check out my edit.  Also, an upvote for my trouble couldn't hurt?